# JPA Spring saving entity to a different name in MariaDB

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The first code block is the entity and the second code saves the tag to the database.

```
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String tagName;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Board> boards = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
public void getTagList(String tagName) {

    Tag tag = new Tag();
    tag.setTagName(tagName);
    tagRepository.save(tag);
}
```

Whenever I send over the tagName, I get an error saying
*java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=564) Unknown column 'tag_name' in 'field list'

- I don't have 'tag_name' anywhere in my code and I'm not sure why JPA is trying to save it with a slightly different name.

I added a column called tag_name in the database and it seems to work and save the data into tag_name.

Comment: It uses `tag_name` because that is the default naming strategy. CamelCase will be converted to `tag_name`. So either rename your field to `tagname` or switch to a different naming strategy, or rename the column in the database.

Comment: Spring/Hibernate doesn't abide by the JPA specification and will override your column definitions. See https://dev.to/aleksey/hibernate-naming-strategies-jpa-specification-vs-spring-boot-opinionation-m1c as you can change the strategy Spring sets for implicit and physical naming.

Answer (score 0):

You can match the DB column name with your field like this.

```
@Column(name="tag_name")
private String tagName;
```